# Sufficient condition for absolute maximum

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-verification, maxima-minima

I am trying to prove or disprove the following statement.

> Let $f : [0, +\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous nonnegative function such that $f(0) = 0$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = 0$. Then $f$ attains an absolute maximum.

I can show that such a function is bounded, but I don't know whether the above statement is true or false. I have tried to prove it using some ideas from the proof of Weierstrass extreme value theorem, but I was not successful. Could anyone give a hint for the proof or a counterexample?

**EDIT**. Using [Jack D'Aurizio's comment below](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2331382/sufficient-condition-for-absolute-maximum#comment4799639_2331382), I think I can prove the statement.
If $f \equiv 0$, then the statement is trivial. Otherwise, there exists $x_1 \in [0, +\infty)$ such that $f(x_1) > 0$. Since $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = 0$, there exists $x_0 \geqslant x_1$ such that
\begin{equation*}
|f(x)| \leqslant f(x_1) \quad \forall \, x \geqslant x_0.
\end{equation*}
By Weierstrass's theorem, there exists $\overline{x} \in [0, x_0]$ such that $f(x) \leqslant f(\overline{x}) \enspace \forall \, x \in [0, x_0]$. Besides, $f(x_1) \leqslant f(\overline{x})$, because $x_1 \in [0, x_0]$. Then, we have
\begin{equation*}
f(x) \leqslant f(x_1) \leqslant f(\overline{x}) \quad \forall \, x \geqslant x_0.
\end{equation*}
$f(\overline{x})$ is the maximum value of $f$ on $[0, +\infty)$.

Is this proof correct? If it is, can it be improved?

Comment: Try to exploit that any continuous function attains a maximum over a closed interval. What do you get by assuming that $f$ *does not* attain an absolute maximum?

Comment: Consider that $\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=0$ implies that for any $\varepsilon>0$ there is some $x_0$ ensuring $\left| f(x)\right|\leq \varepsilon$ for *any* $x\geq x_0$. For short: the tail does not matter. We may focus on the $[0,x_0]$ interval only.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I edited the question following your suggestion. Thanks.